# Is it possible to preview a wordpress post remotely without publishing it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am struggling with remote post preview using wordpress api.
Currently I am publishing new post, capturing html and deleting post.
This works, but I am looking for better solution.

I have an app which is publishing posts remotely to Wordpress. I need to add functionality of post preview on somebody's blog which will be viewed in my app. I need to get full html of wordpress site with post content which is held in my app. I am publishing post using this: [http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/post/sites/%24site/post‌​s/](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/post/sites/%24site/post%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bs/)… capturing html and deleting this post. This solution has lot of disadvantages, for example when wordpress user inform his readers about new post via email, readers will get a notification about new post that doesn't exists any more.

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to achive? What have you tried already? So many questions..

Comment: sure, sorry. I have an app which is publishing posts remotely to Wordpress. I need to add an functionality of post preview on somebody's blog which will be viewed in my app. I need to get full html of wordpress site with post content which is held in my app. I am publishing post using this: https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/post/sites/%24site/posts/new/  capturing html and deleting this post. This solution has lot of disadvantages, for example when wordpress user inform his readers about new post via email, readers will get a notification about new post that doesn't exists any more.

Comment: I've just added your comment to the question body.